# Find most upper parent window with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to find the most parent body element of a document, if you're using a lot of frames. Inside a iframe that also is in a few iframes, I want to call a function for the most upper document body.

The following works, except that you have to count for the parents each time.

```
$(parent.parent.parent.parent.document.body).function('loading');
```

Isn't there something like this?;

```
$(parentOfAllParents.document.body).function('loading');
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `window.top`.

[Specification is here](http://www.w3.org/TR/Window/#window-embedding).

Answer (score 5):

This does the trick from any `iframe`: `top.window.document.body`