# How to get the parent iframe's parent iframe using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have a page `index.html` with an iframe:

```
<iframe src="iframe1.html" width="500" height="400"></iframe>
```

In `iframe1.html` I have another nested iframe:

```
<iframe src="iframe2.html" width="500" height="400"></iframe>
```

In `iframe2.html` I have this code:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('change-color').onclick = function() {
        window.parent.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
        return false;
    };
}
</script>

<a href="" id="change-color">Change Color</a>
```

What happens now when you click the "change color" link is the iframe's parent page `iframe1.html` gets a red background color. Instead I want parent's parent page `index.html` to get the color change. How to access that?

Comment: Maybe `window.parent.parent.document.body.style.backgroundColor`?

Comment: @Barmar on man that did it thanks! I was trying variations but missed that one. If you answer I'll accept.

Comment: You can use window.parent.parent or window.top Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11313045/when-to-use-window-opener-window-parent-window-top

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `window.parent.parent` to get the grandparent window. So you want:

```
window.parent.parent.document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

And if you want the top-most parent, no matter how many levels deep you are, you can use `window.top`. See

[Find most upper parent window with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13839828/find-most-upper-parent-window-with-javascript)